# Default value on Zend_Form_Element_Select

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

There is still a part of me which things this Zend thing is a horrible mess that some how forgives it self at a later stage, But it follows no structure and the documentation is horrible, Which always leads me to a fortunate place which is **stackoverflow**.

So my problem is, That im trying to initialize a `<select>` and i want to have a default value of `Please Choose One`, If a user end up choosing `Please Choose One` as a value, I want to throw an error. The way im doing it dosent work because i cant negative match the regex, ***Or Can I?***

```
$pubs = array(
        "Please Choose One" => "Please Choose One",
        "BBC" => "BBC",
        "Channel 4" => "Channel 4"
);

$channels = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("publication");
$channels->setLabel("Channels")
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addMultiOptions($pubs)
    ->addValidator('regex', true, array(
            "pattern" => "/Please Choose One/",
            "messages" => array("regexNotMatch" => "Please choose a publisher")
        )
    )
    ->setValue("Please Choose One");
```

*P.S I dont mind changing the thing around and use a better methodology.*

Comment: Easy way would be to set the value of the defaut option to '' and set a `notEmpty` validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [Zend_Validate_InArray](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.in_array) instead? It would avoid the need to negate the regexp (which is always a bit tricky).

In your case, it would be something like

> $channels->addValidator('inArray', true, array("BBC" => "BBC",
>   "Channel 4" => "Channel 4"));

Hope that helps,

Comment: Works like a charm, Exactly what im looking for

Answer (score 1):

So you want the select box to be optional but you've got `setRequired(true)`? That doesn't sound right.

In any case, in your multi options if "Please Choose One" is selected, you've got a value of "Please Choose One". I believe you want:

```
$pubs = array(
    null         => "Please Choose One",
    "BBC"        => "BBC",
    "Channel 4"  => "Channel 4"
);
```

Looking at some of my code, when I want a blank item, I'm creating my options array like so:

```
$multiOptions = array();
if (!$options->required) $multiOptions[] = false;
```

So basically starting the multioptions out with a blank spot.

Comment: I see what you mean, by leaving the first element as false. I think you need to give a bigger snippet to really understand what you mean